# spaces between cols in gridlayout

Tags: nativescript

Here's the code:

```
<StackLayout class="m-t-10">
    <Label text="Attached media" textWrap="true" class="p-10 h2 title-2"></Label>
    <GridLayout rows="*, *, *" columns="*, *, *">
        <Image col="0" row="0" src="res://img1" stretch="aspectFill" class="task-media"></Image>
        <Image col="1" row="0" src="res://img1" stretch="aspectFill" class="task-media"></Image>
        <Image col="2" row="0" src="res://img1" stretch="aspectFill" class="task-media"></Image>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I want to add a space between the images in the `col`
[Here is a sample output with the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyQAY.jpg)

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You could either give your `Image`s some margin or add an extra column for the spacing like this (your images will be columns 0,2,4 instead of 0,1,2):

```html
<GridLayout rows="*, *, *" columns="*, 10, *, 10, *">
  <Image col="0" row="0" src="res://img1" stretch="aspectFill" class="task-media"></Image>
  <Image col="2" row="0" src="res://img1" stretch="aspectFill" class="task-media"></Image>
  <Image col="4" row="0" src="res://img1" stretch="aspectFill" class="task-media"></Image>
</GridLayout>
```